# Why is it standard convention to denote dual vectors as row vectors when using coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, dual-spaces, convention

I found this claim in my lecture notes on real analysis in the chapter on the gradient.

> When using coordinates, the standard convention is to denote vectors
>   as columns, and covectors as rows.
>
> The distinction is also essential in physics, as the two kinds of
>   vectors transform differerently under coordinate changes.

I think I understand what they mean with the second sentence. To see this let $e_1,...,e_n$ be and $e',...,e'$ be two bases for the vector space $V$. Given each basis we can find a basis for the dual vector space $V^*$, respectively. In particular,

$e^j(\alpha_1 e_1+...+\alpha_n e_n)=\alpha_j,j=1,...,n$ is a basis for $V^*$ constructed using the basis $e_1,...,e_n$ for $V$.

Similarly,

$(e^i)'(\beta_1 e_1'+...+\beta_n e_n')=\beta_i,i=1,...,n$ is a basis for $V^*$ constructed using the basis $e_1',...,e_n'$ for $V$.

Now let

\begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1,1} & p_{1,2} & \cdots & p_{1,n} \\
p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} & \cdots & p_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
p_{m,1} & p_{m,2} & \cdots & p_{m,n} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

be the $n \times n$ matrix for the change of basis from $e_1,...,e_n$ to $e',...,e'$ and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the column vectors of coordinates for a vector $v \in V$, then

$P \alpha = \beta$ or $\beta_i=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}p_{ij} \cdot \alpha_j$.

This means that

$(e^i)'(v)=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}p_{ij} e^j(v)$.

Now consider

$v^*=\delta_1 (e^1)'+...\delta_n (e^n)'$.

Using the relation between the two bases of $v^*$ we find

$v^*=\delta_1 \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}p_{1j} e^j+...+\delta_n \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}p_{nj} e^j$ which can equivivalently be written as

$v^*=(\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \delta_i p_{i1}) e^1+...+(\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \delta_i p_{in}) e^n=\gamma_1 e^1+...+\gamma_n e^n$

If we write the coordinate vectors $\gamma$ and $\delta$ for $v^* \in V^*$ as row vectors, then

$\delta P=\gamma$ or $\delta=\gamma P^{-1}$, so the change of basis matrix for the dual space is the inverse of the change of basis matrix $P$ for the vector space itself.

However, I can still not see why it is convenient to denote the coordinate vectors for elements of the dual space as row vectors. Can someone explain other reasons why this is useful? Of course, in this case we can avoid transposing the matrix P before inverting (which we would have to do if we wanted to use a column vector of coordinates for the dual space as well), but that seems like a minor thing to me. I feel like it might have something to do with inner products.

Comment: One is a vector the other a linear functional on vectors. So using columns and rows respectively fits in nicely with matrix multiplication.

Comment: One reason is that elements of the dual space are linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb K$, and you already have a matrix representation of such maps, namely as a $1\times m$ matrix.

Comment: @amd Yes, that's clear to me. So is it more like a helpful reminder to not get confused when working with coordinates? Is there an actual relation between the matrix that represents the linear map and the vector of coordinates of this map?

Comment: Of course it is only a convention, and logically one might choose to do this the other way around.  In particular it is common when dealing with Markov chains to represent the state as a row vector and multiply it on the right by a probability state transition matrix.  So matrix multiplication allows us to work either with rows or columns in representing linear mappings.

Comment: The distinction can be blurred in Hilbert spaces, but is sharper without the inner product structure. Separating the two notions in a familiar setting helps when dealing with more general spaces.

Comment: When dealing with differentiation, the distinction helps. I have seen much confusion due to lack of clarity in this regard (derivatives as linear maps, gradients, etc).

Comment: @copper.hat Regarding your first point: Yes, it makes sense to denote vectors as columns because applying a dual vector is a multiplication by 1 $1 \times n$ matrix, but I don't see what this has to do with the coodinate vector for this dual vector. Can you elaborate more on that, please? Or is this convention to ensure that you don't confuse a dual vector for a vector (it does not make sense to multiply two row vectors)?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy: I don't understand what you want me to elaborate, sorry. Yes to the last sentence. Sort of liking typing in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A real $m\times n$ matrix is naturally identified with a linear map from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$. We identify elements of $\Bbb R^n$ as column vectors ($n \times 1$ matrices) mostly because of the longstanding notational tradition of "operator on left, argument on right": $f(x)$ not $(x)f$. Because of how matrix multiplication is defined, matrices multiply column vectors on the left and row vectors on the right.

Now a dual vector is a linear functional on $\Bbb R^m$, which is by definition a linear map from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R$, which means it is naturally associated with an $1 \times m$ matrix. I.e., a row vector.

One could choose to represent $\Bbb R^n$ as row vectors instead (either redefining matrix multiplication, or just acknowledging that writing $vM$ really isn't that big of a deal). But if you do, you will find that dual vectors are naturally column vectors. It is the representation of linear maps as matrices that forces this.

Comment: Thanks for our answer. I am aware that the matrix for a dual vector is a $1 \times m$ matrix or a row vector. But my question was about the coordinate vector of a dual vector. It is easy to see that $e^j, j=1,...,n$ from my question can be represented by $(0...1...0)$ where the $jth$ entry is 1 (it maps $v \in V$ to its $jth$ component). Now let $v^* \in V^*$, then it can represented by $(\gamma_1...\gamma_n)$ and in fact it turns out that $v^*=\gamma_1e^1+...+\gamma_ne^n$. So the matrix representation coincides with the coordinate vector if we write it as a row vector.

Comment: Is that what you are getting at?

Comment: The row vector representation of a linear functional *is* the coordinate vector. If you take a linear functional on $\Bbb R^n$ and express it in terms of the dual basis to the canonical basis on $\Bbb R^n$, you find that the coefficients are exactly the entries in the row vector matrix. So the dual space to $\Bbb R^n$ has a natural *coordinate* representation as a row vector.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That's also what I gave above in my comment. Just wanted to check that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is *consistent* with the usual notation to represent dual vectors as rows:
   A dual vector acts linearly on a vector to give a scalar; it "maps vectors to scalars".
   In the usual matrix representation, vectors are represented by columns and the linear operator is represented by a matrix on the left.

Rows of the matrix act as dual vectors: each row acts linearly on a column (vector) to give a scalar.

2. It is also *convenient*: it is much easier to type a row vector than a column vector. A row vector only takes up a line (if it's not too long).